# onload of import template does not have object instance in `this` - where is it?

Tags: javascript, html5-import

I played around with the html5 imports and JS to create some kind of mvc and now I have a problem.

When I import a template and append its elements to my DOM and register an event it is fired and all is good.
**But then** the `this` instance holds the importet template instead of the object which's property function the binding method is.... :)

Important lines for that issue - to understand the process - have comments near by ....

My question is: How can I alocate the parent object of that method to my `self` variable?

I have some controller parent object:

```
var controller = function(){
};
controller.prototype.import = function(filepath, callback){

    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'import';
    link.href = filepath;
//important line follows
    link.onload = callback;
    link.setAttribute("async", '');
    document.head.appendChild(link);

    return link.import;
};

controller.prototype.display = function(content, selector, target){

    var new_element = content.querySelector(selector);
     document.querySelector(target).appendChild(new_element.cloneNode(true));
};
```

And some xyz-controller extending controller (**here is the problem**):

```
var xyz_controller = function(){
    //behold ... here the callback is defined    
    this.import('/templates/navigation.html', this.init_navigation);
};
xyz_controller.extends(controller);

xyz_controller.prototype.init_navigation = function(){
    //if I console.log(this) it holds the imported template and not xyz_controller??
    var self = this;

    $('#goto-settings').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // calls some method I removed for the example, but here was a problem - I sadly cannot call that function 
        self.settings("param");

        return false;
    });
};
```

The navigation puts the dom elements to the parent document by it selfe like this (this is IN the template file in the end):

```
<script>
    xyz.display(document.currentScript.ownerDocument,'#main-navigation', '#Header');
</script>
```

And there is also some main.JS, which does something with jquery and so:

```
//to inherit all methods from an object
Function.prototype.extends = function(object){
    for(var property in object.prototype){
        this.prototype[property] = object.prototype[property];
    }
};

var xyz;
$( document ).ready(function(){
    xyz = new xyz_controller();
});
```

Comment: is it working if you use bind when you pass the callback?this.import('/templates/navigation.html', this.init_navigation.bind(this));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
link.onload = callback;
```

you assign a function reference. Function references normally do not impose what `this` will be when the function is called. That is only determined when the function is called.

When a function is called, the value for `this` corresponds to the object you call that function on (I oversimplify, see [`this` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). In this case it is the DOM (of the imported document) that calls the callback function, and so that document determines the value of `this`.

Even if you would have assigned it more directly like this, it would still not use your object for `this`:

```
link.onload = this.init_navigation;
```

To avoid that, [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the callback function explicitly to `this`; that will overrule the above described behaviour:

```
link.onload = callback.bind(this);
```

You might find ["How does the “this” keyword work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) an interesting read.

And here is a snippet that illustrates how the `this` keyword behaves differently, depending on whether you use `bind` or not:

```js
var msg = 'I am a window variable<br>';
var test = {
     msg: 'I am a test variable<br>',
     whenLoad: function () {
         document.body.innerHTML += this.msg;
     },
};


window.addEventListener("load",  test.whenLoad); // *this* will be window
window.addEventListener("load",  test.whenLoad.bind(test)); // *this* will be test
```